# Make jQuery Validator Happen Before Submit

Tags: jquery, validation

Is there a way to make the jquery validator check a field one by one as soon as an onkeyup or onblur?

It seems to only process all the fields when the user hits submit, then it shows the error. And then it behaves like a lively validator.

I looked through the docs today and cant find anyway to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#myform").validate().element( "#myselect" );
```

This behaves as validation on blur or keyup, but returns the result.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element

Answer (score 0):

Try the onkeyup option:

```
$(".selector").validate({
   onkeyup: true
})
```

Comment: I had tried this but this works after the forms been submitted, thank you though :)